# Building nested json object

Tags: python, json

I am getting this short of result when ever function `processOutput(output)` is called

```
output = {'LEND': '0', 'LINK': 'Xx', 'REND': '4', 'RULE': ''}
```

Suppose this function called thrice then result json should look like

```
{ 'object[0]' : {'LEND': '0', 'LINK': 'Xx', 'REND': '4', 'RULE': ''},
  'object[1]' : {'LEND': '0', 'LINK': 'Xa', 'REND': '3', 'RULE': 'two'},
  'object[2]' : {'LEND': '0', 'LINK': 'Xz', 'REND': '12', 'RULE': ''}
}
```

so that I can access json values in this way `object[0]['LINK']` and so on

```
def printOutput(self, processed_output):
    #processed_output is output.
```

Comment: Will you please give what you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You should define a counter and output as globals and appending to output every results.

```
output = {}
c = 0

def printOutput(self, processed_output):
    global c, output
    output['object[%i]' % c] = processed_output
    c += 1
```

Comment: thanks but it gives `NameError: global name 'result' is not defined`

Comment: Well, I don't see `result` in any part of the problem question, maybe you'll need to review your code.

Comment: `output` is result in  my case

Comment: `output` is not `result`